# Flutter padding between border and widget

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use Flutter to create a card widget with an icon and a title. But i'm not able to add some margin between border of the cards and the widget.

Here's my card code:

```
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget{
  MyCard({this.title, this.icon});

  final Widget title;
  final Widget icon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
    child: new Card(
      child: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          this.icon,
          new Container(
            width: 20.0, //I also don't know if this is legal
          ),
          this.title
        ]
      )
    )
    );
  }
}
```

That's the result, but I'd like to have more padding inside the card in order to have taller cards and the icons more on the right.

[image: Result]

Comment: Regarding the "I also don't know if this is legal" comment. It's totally ok, the easiest way to add spaces between `Row` items. You can also used `SizedBox` instead of `Container` (internally the `Container` will also creates a `SizedBox`). As seen in the answer of @ap14

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can wrap widgets in card inside [Padding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html) widget or you can use container's [padding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container/padding.html) or [margin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container/margin.html) property to achieve desired layout.

P.S. I have added padding at different levels. Remove or add more padding according to your need.

Code:

```
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget{

 MyCard({this.title, this.icon});

  final Widget title;
  final Widget icon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
        child: new Card(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
              child: new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                      child: this.icon,
                    ),
                    new SizedBox(
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.5, horizontal: 1.0),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                      child: this.title,
                    )
                  ]
              ),
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget{
  MyCard({this.title, this.icon});

  final Widget title;
  final Widget icon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
        child: new Card(
            child: new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
//                  Change Your Code Here
                  new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),child: this.icon,),
                  new Container(
                    width: 20.0, //I also don't know if this is legal
                  ),
                  this.title
                ]
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a good solution. This doesn't add padding on the right of the title

Comment: @boformer it's just a solution you can decorate it more as per your requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Container(
>                       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
>                       decoration: BoxDecoration(
>                         border: Border.all(
>                             color: Theme.of(context).accentColor, width: 3),
>                         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
>                       ),
>                       child: Container(
>                         margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
>                         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
>                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
>                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
>                           color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
>                         ),
>                         child: Text('Evcil Hayvanlar',
>                             style: Theme.of(context)
>                                 .textTheme
>                                 .button
>                                 .copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24)),
>                       ))
> ```

You can try this way also